# How to iterate over an object which have array as value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For Example :

I have an object and in that object, I have values in the array. I want to return the array which contains the key which contains the value passing as a variable.

````
 function getValues(val , object){
  return []; // return [b,c] because xyz are present in both
}

var object = {
     "a" : ["abc", "cde","efg"],
     "b" : ["asdf","asee","xyz"],
     "c" : ["asaw","wewe","xyz"]

  getValues("xyz", object);
}```
````

Comment: you can iterate over the objects values, and iterate each array in turn -  i.e. `const getValues=(val,object)=>Object.entries(object).map(([k,v])=>v?.includes(val)?k:undefined).filter(v=>v);`

Comment: Iterating over an object getting key value should get you started - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to approach this.
One could be using `Object`'s native functions:

```js
function getValues(str, obj) {
  return Object
     // returns the entries pairs in a array of [key, value]
    .entries(obj)
    // from the array it searches the value for the string inputted and maps it back
    .map(([key, array]) => array.includes(str) ? key : undefined)
    // simply remove the undefined returned values from map()
    .filter((value) => value);    
};
```

This could have been done with `reduce()` as well but I found it easier to explain this way.

Another approach is using a `for` loop to iterate over the keys of the object:

```js
function getValues(str, obj) {
  let arr = [];
  // Iterates through the object selecting its keys
  for (let key in obj) {
    // If the array of the current key has the string in it, includes in the array
    if (obj[key].includes(str)) {
      arr.push(key)
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```